# Separating Files Based on their names

Tags: matlab

New to Matlab so this may be more simple than I'm realising.

I'm working with a large number of text files for some data analysis and would like to separate them into a number of categories. They come under a format similar to Tp_angle_RunNum.txt, and Ts_angle_RunNum.text. I would like to have 4 different groups, the Tp and Ts files for angle1, and the same for angle2.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You can use [dir](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-e&q=matlab+dir) to list the folder contents, and then [split](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/split.html) the strings, using `_` as delimiters.

Comment: You can also do `dir('Tp_angle1_*.txt')` to get a list of files in one of your groups, then similar commands for each of the other groups.

Answer (score 0):

A few things here:

1. Remember that your text files are not necessarily going to be where you process your data, so think about how you want to store the data in memory while you work with it.  It *may* be beneficial to pull all of the data into a [MATLAB Table](https://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2022b/matlab/tables.html).  You can read your text files directly into tables with the function [readtable()](https://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2022b/matlab/ref/readtable.html)., with columns to capture Ts, Tp, and angle... or angle1 and angle2.  You can use logicals with all 4, i.e., a true or false as to which group the data row belongs.  You could also capture the run number so you know exactly what file it came from.  Lots of ways to store the data.  But, if you get into very large data sets, Tables are way easier to manipulate and work with.  They are also very fast, and compact if you use categorical types as applicable.
2. dir() will likely be a necessary function for you for the dir listing, however there are some alternatives and some considerations based upon your platform.  I suggest you take a look at the [doc page for dir](https://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2022b/matlab/ref/dir.html).
3. Take advantage of MATLAB Strings and vector processing.  Its not the only way to do things, but it is by far the easiest.  Strings were introduced in R2016b, and have gotten better since as more and more features and capabilities work with strings.  More recently, you can use [patterns](https://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2022b/matlab/ref/pattern.html) instead of (or with!) regular expressions for finding what you need to process.  The doc page I linked above has some great examples, so no point in me reinventing that wheel.
4. [fileparts()](https://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2022b/matlab/ref/fileparts.html) is also your friend in MATLAB when working with many files. You can use it to separate the path, the filename and the extension. You might use it to simplify your processing.
5. Regarding vector processing, you can take an entire array of strings and pass it to the functions used with pattern.  Or, if you take my suggestion of working with tables, you can get rows of your table that match specific characteristics.

Lets look at a few of these concepts together with some sample code.  I don't have your files, but I can demonstrate with just the output of the dir command and some dummy files...  I'm going to break this into two parts, a dirTable function (which is a dir wrapper I like to use instead of dir, and keep on my path) and a script that uses it.  I'd suggest you copy the code and take advantage of code sections to run a section at a time.  See doc page on [Create and Run Sections in Code](https://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2022b/matlab/matlab_prog/create-and-run-sections.html) if this is new to you

**dirTable.m**

```
% Filename: dirTable.m
function dirListing = dirTable( names )
arguments
    names (:,1) string {mustBeText} = pwd()
end

dirListing = table();
for nIdx = 1:numel( names )
    tempListing = dir( names( nIdx ) );
    dirListing = [ dirListing;...
        struct2table( tempListing,'AsArray', true ) ]; %#ok<AGROW>
end
if ~isempty( dirListing )
    %Adjust some of the types...
    dirListing.name = categorical( dirListing.name );
    dirListing.folder = categorical( dirListing.folder );
    dirListing.date = datetime( dirListing.date );
end
end
```

**Example script**

```
%% Create some dummy files - assuming windows, or I'd use the "touch" cmd.
cmds = "type nul >> Ts_42_" + (1:3) + ".txt";
cmds = [cmds;"type nul >> Tp_42_" + (1:3) + ".txt"];
cmds = [cmds;"type nul >> Ts_21_" + (1:3) + ".txt"];
cmds = [cmds;"type nul >> Tp_21_" + (1:3) + ".txt"];
for idx = 1:numel(cmds)
    system(cmds(idx));
end

%% Get the directory listing for all the files
% Note, the filenames come out as categoricals by my design, though that
% doesnt help much for this example - in fact - I'll have to cast to
% convert the categoricals to string a few times.  Thats ok, its not a
% heavy lift.  If you use dir directly, you'd not only be casting to
% string, but you'd also have to deal with the structure and clunky if/else
% conditions everywhere.
listing = dirTable();

%% Define patterns for each of the 4 groups
% - pretending the first code cell doesnt exist.

Tp_Angle1_pattern = "Tp_21";
Ts_Angle1_pattern = "Ts_21";
Tp_Angle2_pattern = "Tp_42";
Ts_Angle2_pattern = "Ts_42";

%% Cycle a group's data, creating a single table from all the files
% I could be more clever here and loop through the patterns as well and
% create a table of tables; however, I am going to keep this code easier
% to read at the cost of repetitiveness.  I will however use a local
% function to gather all the runs from one group into a single table.
Tp_Angle1_matches = string(listing.name).startsWith(Tp_Angle1_pattern);
Tp_Angle1_filenames = string(listing.name(Tp_Angle1_matches));
Tp_Angle1_data = aggregateDataFilesToTable(Tp_Angle1_filenames);

% Repeat for each group...  Or loop the above code for a single table
% if you loop for a single table, make sure to add column(s) for the group
% information


%% My local function for reading all the files in a group
function data_table = aggregateDataFilesToTable(filenames)
arguments
    filenames (:,1) string
end
% We could assume that since we're using run numbers at the end of the 
% filename, that we'll get the filenames pre-sorted for us.  If not zero
% padding the numbers, then need to extract the run number to determine the
% sort order of the files to read in. I'm going to be lazy and assume zero
% padded for simplicity.
data_table = table();  
for fileIdx = 1:numel(filenames)
    % For the following line, two things: 
    % 1) the [data_table;readtable()] syntax appends the table from 
    % readtable to the end of data_table.
    % 2) The comment at the end acknowledges that this variable is growing
    % in a loop, which is usually not the best practice; however, since I
    % have no way of knowing the total table dimensions ahead of time, I
    % cannot pre-allocate the table before the loop - hence the table()
    % call before the for loop.  If you have a way of knowing this ahead of
    % time, do pre-allocate!
    data_table = [data_table;readtable(filenames(fileIdx))]; %#ok<AGROW> 
end
end
```

NOTE 1: using empty parens is not necessary on function calls with no parameters; however, I find it to be easier for others to read when they know they are calling a function and not reading a variable.

NOTE 2: I know the dummy files are empty.  That won't matter for this example, as an empty table appended to an empty table is another empty table.  And the OP's quesiton was about the file manipulation and grouping, etc.

NOTE 3: In case the syntax is new to you, BOTH functions in my example use [function argument blocks](https://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2022b/matlab/ref/arguments.html), which were introduced in R2019b - and they make for much easier to maintain and read code than NOT validating inputs, or using more complex ways of validating inputs. I was going to leave that out of this example, but they were already in my dirTable function, so I figured I'd just explain it instead.